# Random XML animations for an imageView

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I'm making an online radio app for a friend. I was thinking of adding random effects to the image in the background which is their logo, so I've created a couple of samples.

This is a spin animation

```
rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="359"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="6000"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
```

and this is a flashing animation

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="250"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
</set>
```

Question 1 is: how can I make it so the app picks a random animation at random intervals and question 2: how process heavy is using these XML animations? Can I have a few in there?